# How can I test the method that has NSDate() call inside?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, nsdate

```
extension NSDate {
    class func todayDateFromMidnightForSeconds(seconds: NSTimeInterval) -> NSDate {
        let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        let startOfTheCurrentDay = calendar.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())

        return startOfTheCurrentDay.dateByAddingTimeInterval(seconds)
    }
}
```

How can I mock my `NSDate()` inside my custom method to test it in a proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to delete "class" declaration from your method and replace NSDate() with self as follow:

```
extension NSDate {
    func dateFromMidnightForSeconds(seconds: NSTimeInterval) -> NSDate {
        return NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!.startOfDayForDate(self).dateByAddingTimeInterval(seconds)
    }
}

NSDate().dateFromMidnightForSeconds(60)  // "Jun 12, 2015, 12:01 AM"
```

Comment: Better is to use `self` inside instance method than initialise new objects in class methods.